# Thought experiment - Universe that follows $f \propto \frac{1}{r}$ law

Tags: forces, potential-energy, distance, thought-experiment

In our universe, due to reasons usually attributed to the 3D geometry of it, the forces of nature seem to mostly be $\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$, inversely proportional to the distance of the source of the force squared.

However, what would it look like if we lived in a universe where common forces, such as the gravitational force, or the electrostatic force, were instead $\propto \frac{1}{r} -$ simply inversely proportional to the distance from the source of the force?

For example, if the gravitational force obeyed an inverse law  *($f_\text{g} \propto \frac{1}{r}$)* rather than an inverse square law  *($f_\text{g} \propto \frac{1}{r^2} ,$)* the amount of work needed to separate two masses $m$ and $M$ to distances infinitely far away from one another would be infinite.
$$
\int_r^\infty \frac{GMm}{r}
~=~ \left. GMm \ln⁡(r) \right|_r^\infty
~=~ \infty
$$

Similarly, if the electrostatic force obeyed an inverse law instead of an inverse square law, the work a negative charge $Q$ would do on a positive charge $q$ as it attracted it from infinitely far away would be infinite.

We could no longer define “infinitely far away” as a place of zero potential energy, because as $Q$ and $q$ approach being infinitely apart, the work they would do on each other as they were brought closer to a distance $r$ from one another would be infinite.

***What would be the physical consequences of this, of living in a world with an inverse law instead of an inverse square law?***

I can think of one right away: there would be no such thing as an escape velocity. No matter how great the velocity with which you launch a rocket from a planet’s surface into empty (let’s assume space is empty) space, the gravitational force of the planet would eventually cause the rocket to fall back towards the planet.

***What other consequences would there be? What would such a universe look like? Could such a universe even exist, in 2 OR 3 dimensions?***

Comment: $\uparrow$ 2+1D?

Comment: To be more verbose about what Qmechanic is asking, are you asking this question in the context of a 2+1 dimensional universe (2 dimensions of space+1 of time) or a 3+1D universe like our own?

Comment: @Chris yep I got the question, I'm just thinking about it. I guess it makes sense ***geometrically*** that if the world was (2+1)D that forces would be inverse $r$ instead of inverse $r^2$. However, I'm still confused about what the consequences would be...so I guess the answer is...both?

Comment: @Qmechanic both 2+1D and 3+1D! Thanks!

Comment: The new earth gravity will be $g_n=R\,g$ , where R is the earth radius. I assume that G ist constant?